# QTableWidget's information not updating

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I have this window where I have a 'start' button and a QTableWidget. So, when I click the start button it calls a function which has an infinite loop in it and that loop calls another function which adds rows to the Table Widget and inserts texts in the cells. The table widget initially has 3 columns, I added them in QtDesigner. When I break out of the while loop by changing the 'var' to False it updates the QTableWidget and adds the row with a text on it, but I don't want to break out of the loop. I want it to run constantly and update the rows, so that I can see them appear after text is added to them. I've found topics similar to mine and one suggested to use singleshot(), which didn't work for me or maybe I didn't use it right.

Heres my code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableWidgetItem, QMainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import time
import sys

var = True

class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi("test_widget.ui", self)

        self.start_button.clicked.connect(self.loopFunc)
        self.model = self.table.model()

    def addRow(self):
        row_count = self.table.rowCount()
        self.table.insertRow(row_count) # adding a new row

    def setInfo(self):

        self.addRow()

        rows = []
        for row in range(self.model.rowCount()): #getting a list of all the rows
            rows.append(int(row))

        current_row = rows[-1] # getting the last row

        self.table.setItem(current_row, 0, QTableWidgetItem('a'))
        self.table.setItem(current_row, 1, QTableWidgetItem('b'))
        self.table.setItem(current_row, 2, QTableWidgetItem('c'))

        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.setInfo())  # this was meant to update QTableWidget's information
        #var = False

    def loopFunc(self):
        while var is True:
            time.sleep(1)
            self.setInfo()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = Main()
    window.show()

    sys.exit(my_app.exec())
```

If someone could point out what I can do to get my QTableWidget update that'd be great!!

Comment: Loops are blocking (which prevent the event loop to properly process UI interaction and repainting) and should never be used unless they exit as soon as possible. The argument of QTimer (as with any signal connection) must be the callable, but you are *actually calling* the function; also, a 0 interval is too short. Change to `QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1000, self.setInfo)`, or, better, create the timer in the init as an instance attribute so that you can stop it when needed: `self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(interval=1000, timeout=self.setInfo)` `self.start_button.clicked.connect(self.timer.start)`

Comment: @musicamante Thank you for your fast response! Last 2 lines of code that you suggested fixed the updating problem but now I can't scroll the window to see the other rows. What can I do to fix that?
Thank you once more:)

Comment: I don't know what you mean, and since your code doesn't include the UI I cannot help you with that. Note that if you only need to access the last row, using the for loop is unnecessary: `current_row = self.table.rowCount() - 1`. Also your `var = False` wouldn't have worked unless you used `global var`, but globals are discouraged (this is pointless since the loop shouldn't have been used anyway, but it's just for your knowledge).

Comment: I added it last second and forgot to use global:D Anyways I don't use it in my real code. And current_row line is for sure simpler. I haven't thought of it. Thank you very much!